# App widget xml layout for variable parent size

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have an app widget which is resizable. I want to have text above and below an image. The image should take as much room as available and the text should be directly above and below the image.

I want to do this in xml only, but can't figure out a layout which works for both situations shown in the attached image.

So my question is, with what XML can I achieve this behavior?

EDIT: The image view may be larger than the parent container view.

[image: desired layout behavior]

Comment: Use RelativeLayout with the image defined first.  Use center alignment in the parent.  Then the two textviews, one using layoutAbove and the other using layoutBelow.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/imageview"
        android:text="text 1"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview"
        android:text="text 2"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Or this, using layout weight to control the sizing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:text="text 1"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:text="text 2"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Play with the weights, the image alignment and the image scale type to get it just how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried this layout and it doesn't work for scenario 1. The image will fill all the available height, leaving the text views not shown. (btw I had to also add adjustviewbounds=true to make your suggested layout work in scenario 2)

Comment: I've edited with another possible solution.  I also edited the RelativeLayout to include scaleType.

Comment: Thanks again, but playing with the weights doesn't work for Scenario 1. The blue textviews either get cut off, or take up more room than they should if they were just wrapping their content...